# Can I hack Ctrl-arrow key stop points?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, text-editing, cursor

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> in a text field, the cursor jumps to the beginning or end of a word.  It stops at dashes, but not periods.

It stops at white space, but not brackets, colons, or semi-colons.  I would much prefer that Ctrl-arrow key stop at all punctuation.  Can I hack that behavior into my PC?  Where should I begin?

Comment: It depends on what text editor you are using. So what text editor are you using?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I use Npp, but I was also thinking Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about usual EDIT fields (e.g. Windows Run menu) or **Notepad**, then u cannot hack it. It's better done in external text editors: **Notepad++**, **SynWrite** (Synw copies behaviour of Notepad++), Akelpad (it has option which chars are word-chars and are stops) etc.

Comment: But there's no method in your answer or terminology so that the method can be researched.